# OOP basics of how objects are created

Tags: java, oop

Following oo situation:

```
class A{
        public A(){ System.out.println("Regular constructor of A"); }
        public A(int i){ System.out.println("Constructor of A with " + i); }
    }

    class B extends A{
        public B(){
            super(3);
            System.out.println("Regular constructor of B");
        }
        public B(int i){ System.out.println("Constructor of B with " + i); }
    }
```

I am practicing **oo programming**. What happens if I initiate an object this way?

```
B b1 = (B) new A();
```

However such a type cast doesn't make sense to me. What would be the output? Please describe why.

Comment: Have you tried running this? The output is self-explanatory.

Comment: You can use an online compiler to test stuff like this out if you don't have a compiler/Java installation handy.  Here's an example: http://ideone.com/hMNcF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output will be an exception when you try to cast to B, like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: A cannot be cast to B
    at Test.main(Test.java:16)
```

An instance of "just an A" *isn't* an instance of B, which is why the cast fails.

Now you *could* do this:

```
A a = new B();
B b = (B) a; // No exception!
```

because in that case although the type of the `a` variable is just `A`, its *value* refers to an instance of `B`... so the cast succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

[ClassCastException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html)

```
B extends A
```

You can not cast A to B because A is **not** B

```
(B) A // class cast exception
```

with the same logic B is A so

```
(A) B // true
```